# Events like google calendar in a custom view day calendar

Tags: android, listview, view, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm developing a little calendar app with a day view and a week view. 
That app is like a Google Calendar android app and it must include events as the original Google's app does.

The app is based on a ListView.

I was thinking to develop the events with an overlayed views. Can anyone guide me please? To be honest, i'm pretty lost =p

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, the easiest (and I think best) solution would be to simply have some kind of ViewGroup (e.g. LinearLayout), as each listelement (look at ListView and especially at Adapters if you don't know how to do that ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) ). In your adapter's getView() you can then add your events as e.g. TextViews...

Your question is actually a little too broad to give you a real answer...but maybe it gives you a place to start, and you can ask more specific questions, if necessary...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! ;) What I'm actually trying to ask, is how to develope the event boxes, and put them into the "calendar".

Uhm... it has to looks like that: [image](http://yfrog.com/ne80gtp)

In case to have many events at the same time, they must be displayed as diferent boxes one beside the other one. Overlapped events boxes not needed.
I hope I explained better this time. Thank you very much!!

Comment: ok, i understand why you wanted to use overlayed views now. However I start to think that a listview might not be the right choice, but that you maybe should think about writing a custom view, where you draw both the calender and the events "manually" ( see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html ). Things like handling clicks might get a little more complicated, but I currently couldn't think of another possibility using standard views :/